# How do I use the math.h function in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I used the functions `cos(x)`, `sin(x)` .... from math.h on Windows but Ubuntu 15.10 tells me that *undefined reference to cos...*

Answer (score 6):

When you compile the code, add `-lm` to the *gcc* command, example

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -o program source.c -lm
```

this will tell the linker to link to *libm.so* where the definitions for the *math.h* functions are.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile it with -lm

```
gcc -o namefile namefile.c -lm
```

Comment: @iharob Is it a general advice o specifically for this case? I commonly use -Wall for "debugging" purpose

Comment: General advice. It's not for debugging. It helps detecting silly mistakes.

Comment: @iharob yes, that's what I meant for debugging

Comment: When telling someone that didn't know about linking to the *libm.so*, don't you think that `-Wall` is required for them?

Comment: @iharob yes, you are right. From now on I'll use -Wall every time as well. I'm still learning C and this is one of the reason I'm here on SO. I'm trying to enhance my capability and skill, testing what I know answering and questioning whenever I have a doubt I can't afford my self.